# Getting constant pauses on a Gatling Scenario

Tags: gatling

Gatling noob here. I'm trying to work on a scenario which spreads across 10 minutes and fires an http request every 10 seconds. I have the below code but it seems to 'ignore' the pauses clause. Any ideas?

Gatling version: 2.2.0

```
  myScenario.inject(
  nothingFor(10),
  constantUsersPerSec(1) during (10 minutes))
  .pauses(uniformPausesPlusOrMinusDuration(10 seconds)),
```

Comment: Hi ravenblizard, Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I ended up using this: constantUsersPerSec(0.1)

Comment: How did you determine the '0.1' number?

Comment: By trial and error.